# Want to build a guided tour for the first launch

Tags: flutter, user-interface

at the moment I am building an app with flutter.
Now that I have some function done I want to build a guided tour for new user, which explains some of the basic of the app. I want this to pop up if a new user starts the app for the first time and it should also be accessible later.

Do you have some suggestions what widget can be used for that? I thought abount something like 5 pages which you can flip trough - with pictures and text.

Hope you understand what I am looking for.
An example would be great.

Thanks in advance
Patrick

Answer (score 1):

maybe You can use showcaseview package.
https://pub.dev/packages/showcaseview

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about an onboarding screen, there is a [package](https://pub.dev/packages/introduction_screen) you can use for that.

To "persist" the state of onbarding completion, you can use [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) to create a value where you will check on app startup

```dart
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.setBool('onboarding',true); // call this when onbarding is finished
var isOnbCompleted = prefs.getBool('onboarding'); // to get the value
if (isOnbCompleted)
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - thats exactly what I am looking for.